# Questions about the authenticity of artifacts

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Are questions about the authenticity of a given artifact off-topic? If so, are there any sites on SE for these types of questions?

Comment: Historical Artifacts? Religious artifacts?   To my mind the answer is "If the artifact can be proven authentic through historical sources & methods, then very likely yes.  If authenticity must be proven through other disciplines, then No.".   Could you clarify the question?

Comment: I mean questions like, "I have this ancient Egyptian scarab and was wondering if it's authentic"

Comment: I would be skeptical of such questions. Certainly we could point out obvious means of detecting a fake, but the only conclusion is "My fake wasn't made by a total idiot!"  I doubt we could convey the knowledge, skills and abilities to authenticate an artifact. The best approach is to take it to a professional.